# Replace NaN inside a Column by another Dataframe using a Condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, fillna

I have a Dataframe like below and we have NaN only inside column 'Type 2':

| id | Type 1 | Type 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b |
| 1 | c | d |
| 2 | e | NaN |
| 3 | g | f |
| 4 | i | h |
| 5 | j | k |
| 6 | l | NaN |
| 7 | m | NaN |
| 8 | o | p |
| 9 | x | y |
| 9 | z | NaN |

And another one is an ordered Dataframe like Below:

| id | Type 1 | Type 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | o1 |
| 1 | b | o2 |
| 2 | c | o3 |
| 3 | d | o4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 23 | x | o24 |
| 24 | y | o25 |
| 25 | z | o26 |

I want to fill NaN inside column 'type 2' with the second Dataframe Type 2 correspond Type 1.
I know I should use fillna() but I do not know how to add conditions like above, I wrote.

Thank you

Comment: fillna with `df1['Type 1'].map(df2.set_index('Type 1')['Type 2']`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked :)